# Assigning the datatable to other datatable value

Tags: c#-4.0

I have noticed that when assigning one datatble values to other datatable,if i changed the new  datatable values the other datatable(old) value also change.as i am beginner i dint understand  why can anyone help me to solve.
example:

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = dtRpt;//dtrpt contains some value
                dt.Columns.Remove("KidoTotal");
                dt.Columns.Remove("Total");
                dt.Columns.Remove("intSubjectID");
```

Comment: Datatables are by ref. Create a clone or a copy to do actions in datatable and not change in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataTable` is a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx), so if you assign another `DataTable` reference to your variable both are actually the same table.

You need to copy the data to a new table with the same schema, you can use `DataTable.Copy`:

```
DataTable dt = dtRpt.Copy();  // use Clone if you want to create an empty table without data with the same schema
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the above :

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = dtRpt.Clone();//dtrpt contains some value
        dt.Columns.Remove("KidoTotal");
        dt.Columns.Remove("Total");
        dt.Columns.Remove("intSubjectID");
```

[Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) is only for schema. If you need and data use  [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx)